# AWS CodeBuild skip few stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

We have AWS Codepipeline which executes the build via git webhooks. It works perfect.

Is there any way to skip the deployment in staging and deploy directly to the production (to fix some urgent bug or revert to last commit without waiting for 40-50mins to complete the pipeline from start to prod)?